# Как сделать переключатель из Click?

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

У меня есть одна кнопка, которая имеет две иконки. Как сделать, чтобы при каждом нажатии кнопки эти 2 иконки чередовали (1-2-1-2-1) ???

Comment: Вопрос из ряда - Дайте ка я вам вынесу мозг... html код своей чудокнопки хотя бы покажите?!

Comment: скорее всего, 

    <TABLE border.... 

;)

Answer (score 1):

я вас правильно понял? >

1. http://jsfiddle.net/wanchucha/LFEae/1/
2. http://jsfiddle.net/wanchucha/LFEae/

Answer (score 0):

при инициализации:

```
$('#my_button').data('status',1);
```

При нажатии:

```
$('#my_button').data('status',1-$('#my_button').data('status'));
$('#my_button').css('background-image','url('+$('#my_button').data('status')+'.jpg'+')');
```

Как-то так. 
Иконки называются 1.jpg и 0.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Ну или вот так: http://jsfiddle.net/44Hpv/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Jm2W4/

CSS:

```
.state-on,
.pressed .state-off {
    display: none;
}
.pressed .state-on {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="demo">
    <img src="..." class="state-off"/>
    <img src="..." class="state-on" />
    <span> click me </span>
</button>
```

JS:

```
// Modern browsers
demo.addEventListener('click', function (evt){
    evt.currentTarget.classList.toggle('pressed');
}, false);

// or jQuery
$('#demo').on('click', function (evt){
    $(evt.currentTarget).toggleClass('pressed');
});
```